# NameError in defining python multi-level package

Tags: python, package, nameerror

I'm trying to create a simple multi-level package:

```
test_levels.py
level1/
        __init__.py (empty file)
        level2/
                __init__.py  (only contents: __all__ = ["leaf"])
                leaf.py
```

leaf.py:

```
class Leaf(object):
    print("read Leaf class")
    pass

if __name__ == "__main__":
    x = Leaf()
    print("done")
```

test_levels.py:

```
from level1.level2 import *
x = Leaf()
```

Running leaf.py directly works fine, but running test_levels.py returns the output below, 
where I was expecting no output:

```
read Leaf class
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Dev\intranet\test_levels.py", line 2, in <module>
    x = Leaf()
NameError: name 'Leaf' is not defined
```

Can someone point out what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to add

```
from leaf import *
```

in file level1/level2/__init__.py

upd: as in previous comment, add dot before module name, and remove "__all__" declaration.

```
$ cat level1/level2/__init__.py
from .leaf import Leaf
$ cat level1/level2/leaf.py
class Leaf:
    def __init__(self):
        print("hello")
$ cat test.py
from level1.level2 import *
x = Leaf()
$ python test.py
hello
```

Comment: I think `from .leaf` will only work in Python 3 (or if you import absolute_imports from `__future__` in Python 2).

Comment: Yes, but i think that topicstarter uses exactly python3, because he wrote print(...) instead of print ...

Comment: OK, looking at the documentation, I think `from .leaf` should work from Python 2.5 onwards. The dot is only required in Python 3--it means that leaf is in the same package as the file importing from it.

Answer (score 0):

In `level1/level2/__init__.py`, I think you want to do `from leaf import *` (or, in Py3k, `from .leaf import *`).

When you import from `level1.level2`, you're really importing the `__init__.py` file in that directory. Since you haven't defined `Leaf` in there, you don't get it by importing that.

Comment: I am using Python 2.6, and adding from leaf import * to level1/level2/__init__.py works, but given that it's contents are already:
__all__ = ["leaf"]
and that "read Leaf class" is in the output, shouldn't it be working already? or can the __all__ not be used in this context?

Comment: `__all__` sets the list of names that will be used by `from <name> import *`, but those names still have to be defined in that context. In your structure, the Leaf class is in `level1.level2.leaf`. So, in test_levels.py, you could call `leaf.Leaf()`. Or you could do `from level1.level2.leaf import *`.

Answer (score 0):

Are you expecting to import all the variable names from all the modules in that package? That's a horrible idea. To do what you want, it should be

```
from level1.level2.leaf import *
```

or even better yet to remove the wildcard import, which is usually bad, it should be

```
from level1.level2.leaf import Leaf
```